# How to get Name of an item corresponding to Min and Max value in a grouped set into different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

**Table 1**: ORDERS (ORDER_ID, CUSTOMER_ID, ITEM_ID, QUANTITY)

**Table 2**: CUSTOMERS (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME, ZIPCODE)

**Table 3**: ITEMS (ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME)

**Required Output**: OUTPUT (ZIPCODE, MAX_ORDERED_ITEM_NAME, MIN_ORDERED_ITEM_NAME

I've tried various approaches to get the output, but haven't been able to get to the end result

Current query:

```
SELECT ZIPCODE, ITEM_NAME, SUM(QUANTITY) AS SALES
FROM ORDERS
JOIN CUSTOMERS ON ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID
JOIN ITEMS ORDERS.ITEM_ID = ITEMS.ITEM_ID
GROUP BY ZIPCODE, ITEM_NAME
ORDER BY SALES DESC;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: @jarlh I'm using Oracle SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function `ROW_NUMBER` with the `group by` as following:

> ```
> SELECT O.ZIPCODE, 
> MAX(CASE WHEN MAXRN = 1 THEN ITEM_NAME END) AS MAX_ORDERED_ITEM_NAME,
> MAX(CASE WHEN MINRN = 1 THEN ITEM_NAME END) AS MIN_ORDERED_ITEM_NAME
> FROM 
> (SELECT
>     O.ZIPCODE, I.ITEM_ID, I.ITEM_NAME,
>     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I.ITEM_ID ORDER BY SUM(QUANTITY) ) AS MINRN,
>     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I.ITEM_ID ORDER BY SUM(QUANTITY) DESC NULLS LAST) AS MAXRN
> FROM
>     ORDERS O
>     JOIN ITEMS I ON I.ITEM_ID = O.ITEM_ID
>     JOIN CUSTOMERS C ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID
>     GROUP BY O.ZIPCODE, I.ITEM_ID, I.ITEM_NAME)
> WHERE 1 IN (MINRN, MAXRN)
> GROUP BY O.ZIPCODE;
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: We're already using WHERE condition which specifically looks at ROW_NUMBER 1 in both the partitions, so can you please explain the logic behind MAX (CASE ***) in the outer select ?
My assumption is that because the outer select is being aggregated at zipcode level, we need to have other dimensions aggregated as well ?